# Javascript - Mix two arrays of objects ordering by date and without repetitions

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two lists:

```
let originalDocs = [
  {
    id: "sara",
    date: new Date("01/01/2022")
  },
  {
    id: "vic",
    date: new Date("10/26/2020")
  }
];

let newDocs = [
   {
     id: "vic",
     date: new Date("01/02/2022")
   },
   {
     id: "raul",
     date: new Date("05/05/2021")
   }
];
```

I need to mix both lists, ordering by date (in descending order) and without repetitions.

In order to do that, I have decided to:

1. Delete the set of elements of the original array that are included in the new array (I mean, deleting the intersection) without modifying the original array.
2. Mix the resulted array ordering by date.

This is my current code:

```js
function removeIntersection(originalDocs, newDocs) {
  return  originalDocs.filter((originalDoc) => {
    const index = newDocs.findIndex(
      (newDoc) => newDoc.id === originalDoc.id
    );

    return index === -1;
  });
}

function mixInOrder(originalDocs, newDocs) {
   return [...newDocs, ...originalDocs]
    .sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
}


//
// MAIN
//

let originalDocs = [
  {
    id: "sara",
    date: new Date("01/01/2022")
  },
  {
    id: "vic",
    date: new Date("10/26/2020")
  }
];

let newDocs = [
  {
    id: "vic",
    date: new Date("01/02/2022")
  },
  {
    id: "raul",
    date: new Date("05/05/2021")
  }
];

const result = mixInOrder(
  removeIntersection(originalDocs, newDocs),
  newDocs
);

console.log(result);
```

How can I do the same in a more optimal way, I mean, without the need of merging (using the spread syntax) the list before sorting it, or deleting the intersection in O(1).

I mean, is it possible to just insert in order avoiding the copy?

Comment: If an item with the same `id` exists in both arrays, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: @tao In the example snippet, the OP takes an item from `newDocs`

Comment: @tao, the one that is included in the second list "newDocs".

Comment: @404, upsss, I meant to delete the intersection but without modifying this array. I am executing this code in a reducer, so I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this using a JS Map, where you use the `id` as identifier:

```js
let originalDocs = [
  {
    id: "sara",
    date: new Date("01/01/2022")
  },
  {
    id: "vic",
    date: new Date("10/26/2020")
  }
];

let newDocs = [
  {
    id: "vic",
    date: new Date("01/02/2022")
  },
  {
    id: "raul",
    date: new Date("05/05/2021")
  }
];
const map = new Map(originalDocs.map(el => [el.id, el]));
newDocs.forEach(el => map.set(el.id, el));
const sorted = [...map.values()].sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
console.log(sorted)
```

This overrides any `originalDocs` entry with a `newDocs` entry if they have the same `id`.

Comment: Using findIndex every iteration will never be the most optimal approach

Comment: I thought `findIndex` is fast. What would be an optimal approach?

Comment: Creating a Map or object using id as keys will be far more efficient since the look ups are o(1) whereas findIndex is o(n)

Comment: So you're saying the most efficient way would be to merge them and then `order` into a new copy?

Comment: OP is already creating new array, not mutating original as you are doing

Comment: it should be b.date - a.date (when sorting)

Comment: What is the Big O of this solution?

Comment: I think it's `O(n + n log n)`. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as:

- Create a new array by adding the `originalDocs` first and then `newDocs` afterwards.
- Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop over the newly created array and then filter the objects.

> You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to check for existence of a key in efficient way

- After filtering, you can then sort it accordingly.

```js
let originalDocs = [
  {
    id: 'sara',
    date: new Date('01/01/2022'),
  },
  {
    id: 'vic',
    date: new Date('10/26/2020'),
  },
];

let newDocs = [
  {
    id: 'vic',
    date: new Date('01/02/2022'),
  },
  {
    id: 'raul',
    date: new Date('05/05/2021'),
  },
];

const set = new Set();
const result = [...originalDocs, ...newDocs].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!set.has(curr.id)) {
      acc.push(curr);
      set.add(curr.id);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
console.log(result);
```